# subset dataframe based on combination of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have 2 dataframes. Truncated examples of these dataframes are:

dataSC_ds

```
SURVEY_DATE SITE
2012-07-01  Site 1
2012-08-10  Site 2
2012-09-15  Site 1
2012-09-20  Site 1
...
```

and

dataSC

```
 SURVEY_DATE  FISHING_SITE  DATA_COLLECTION_SITE  SHIFT  TIME_BLOCK
 2012-07-01   Site 1                              AM     9
 2012-07-01                 Site 1                AM     9
 2012-07-02   Site 2                              AM     11
 2012-07-02                 Site 2                AM     11
 2012-07-15   Site 3                              PM     15
 2012-07-15                 Site 3                PM     15
 2012-08-10   Site 2                              PM     16
 2012-08-10                 Site 2                PM     16
 2012-08-20   Site 2                              AM     11
 2012-08-20                 Site 2                AM     11
 2012-09-15   Site 1                              AM     9
 2012-09-15                 Site 1                AM     9
 2012-09-15   Site 1                              AM     10
 2012-09-15                 Site 1                AM     10
 2012-09-20   Site 1                              PM     13
 2012-09-20                 Site 1                PM     13
 2012-09-20   Site 3                              PM     15
 2012-09-20                 Site 3                PM     15
 ...
```

I would like to subset dataSC to retain the rows with the combinations of date & site that are in dataSC_ds. The complicated part is that given

```
2012-07-01  Site 1
```

in dataSC_ds, I would like to retain in dataSC the rows with 2012-07-01 in which Site 1 is either a FISHING_SITE or a DATA_COLLECTION_SITE.

Please let me know if you have any ideas about how I can do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your data has some redundancy. Can't the fishing and the collection sites be in the same observation? Nevertheless, you can use `mapply` to subset the data with all the different sites.

```
# make a function to subset the data
select <- function(x, y) dataSC[dataSC$SURVEY_DATE== y & (dataSC$FISHING_SITE==x | dataSC$DATA_COLLECTION_SITE==x), ]

#apply the function with all elements of dataSC_ds$SITE
subsets <- mapply(select, x=dataSC_ds$SITE, y=dataSC_ds$SURVEY_DATE, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

#name the data.frames of the list with data and site
subsets <- setNames(subsets, paste(dataSC_ds$SURVEY_DATE, dataSC_ds$SITE))
```

This will give you a list with all the subsets:

```
subsets

$`2012-07-01 Site 1`
  SURVEY_DATE FISHING_SITE DATA_COLLECTION_SITE SHIFT TIME_BLOCK
1  2012-07-01       Site 1                         AM          9
2  2012-07-01                            Site 1    AM          9

$`2012-08-10 Site 2`
  SURVEY_DATE FISHING_SITE DATA_COLLECTION_SITE SHIFT TIME_BLOCK
7  2012-08-10       Site 2                         PM         16
8  2012-08-10                            Site 2    PM         16

$`2012-09-15 Site 1`
   SURVEY_DATE FISHING_SITE DATA_COLLECTION_SITE SHIFT TIME_BLOCK
11  2012-09-15       Site 1                         AM          9
12  2012-09-15                            Site 1    AM          9
13  2012-09-15       Site 1                         AM         10
14  2012-09-15                            Site 1    AM         10

$`2012-09-20 Site 1`
   SURVEY_DATE FISHING_SITE DATA_COLLECTION_SITE SHIFT TIME_BLOCK
15  2012-09-20       Site 1                         PM         13
16  2012-09-20                            Site 1    PM         13
```